# VBA - getting data that has same header from different sheets

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first question on Stackoverflow, although I've been using the forum for a while, trying to teach myself VBA. So here goes my very first very long post:

I have a workbook(1) containing a worksheet(general data) and  need to fill it with Data from other workbooks(n) that contain sheets(sheet1). I would like to use VBA for this because doing it manually is very time consuming and prone to mistakes. 
The way the data that needs to be copied is identified, is via  headers (i.e. LIFNR). On sheet(general data) the position and order of these headers can vary and in workbooks(n).sheet1 the order in which the headers are can vary (although they are always in row 1).

I have managed to write a working code, but it seems like a bit of a Rube Goldberg machine... and tedious because I'll have about 30 headers and 5 workbooks(n) to apply this to. Is there a better and faster way to achieve what I'm doing? Here's the code:

```
 'Define the individual header names
Sub DataGrab()
Dim sdLIFNR, nLIFNR As Range
Dim ws1, wsn As Worksheet
Dim wb1, wbn As Workbook
Dim fdn As FileDialog
Dim data As String
Dim LastCol1, LatRow1, LastColn, LastRown As Integer

'Define worksheet(1) & worsheet(n)
Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("General Data")

'Pick a file via file dialog
Set fdn = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fdn
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Title = "Please select the file containing the Bank data"
.Filters.Clear
If .Show = True Then
data = fdn.SelectedItems(1)
Else: GoTo CancelBox
End If
End With

Set wbn = Workbooks.Open(data)
Set wsn = wbn.Sheets("Sheet1")


'Find last non empty column and row in sheet(general data)

LastRow1 = ws1.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row
LastCol1 = ws1.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Column
 'get position of where LIFNR is in sheet(n)
 wsn.Activate
 Set nLIFNR = wsn.Range("A1").EntireRow.Find("LIFNR", LookAt:=xlWhole)

'get position of where LIFNR is in sheet(general data)
ws1.Activate
Set sdLIFNR = ws1.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow1, LastCol1)).Find("LIFNR", LookAt:=xlWhole)

'Find lastrow in sheet(n)
wsn.Activate
LastRown = wsn.Cells(Rows.Count, nLIFNR.Column).End(xlUp).Row

ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(LastRow1 + 1, sdLIFNR.Column), ws1.Cells(LastRow1 + LastRown - 1, sdLIFNR.Column)) = wsn.Range(wsn.Cells(2, nLIFNR.Column), wsn.Cells(LastRown, nLIFNR.Column)).Value
Exit Sub

CancelBox:
MsgBox "You didn't select all the files required for this makro. Please restart this makro and try again"

End Sub
```

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: It looks like your code above is searching for the `LIFNR` header name within the `General Data` workbook? and then finding the last row and value?  If you know the names of the headers and workbook and they will never change, adding some parameters to your `DataGrab(param1, param2)` subroutine.  For example, you could write another subroutine that `Call DataGrab(param1, param2)` and uses variables in place of your hard coded header and file name.

Comment: I'm using Excel 2016 @CRUTER using variables instead of the hard coded header file names sounds like a good idea. I'll try to figure out a way to maybe loop through the code I have and change the variable each time it loops through. If anyone knows how to do this or has a useful link I'd be grateful for a point in that direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could mention header names in a range on a control sheet and define them as a range . Later you can refer to each cell value to get the header name and from there look for each one in the header row .

'mapping is a range here and a is the string variable associated to the first name in range . Ey is a range . '.column ' function will give the column number of the header word Rng will store the corresponding column alphabet like D when column number is 4

Sr  Column Name
a   Reference
c   Branch Code
d   Book Balance - Local CCY
e   End Date (Value Date)

above is the range Mapping defined in two columns of control sheet

```
map = Range("Mapping")

a = map(1, 2) ' here a will store the value reference

basedata.Activate   'Its a workbook
sheet.activate      ' Its a worksheet in basedata workbook    
Set Ey = basedata.ActiveSheet.Rows("1").Find(What:=a, LookIn:=xlValues,LookAt:=xlWhole)
f1 = Ey.Column

Cells(2, f1).Select
Rng = ActiveCell.Address
Rng = Replace(Rng, "2", "")
Rng = Replace(Rng, "$", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to achieve what I wanted to do by new sheets that contained the headers. Thanks for your helpful suggestions, they got me on the right track! I chose to not assign variables to Header names because it made the code easier to read. Here is my complete working code below for anyone who's interested:

```
    Sub DataGrab()
    Dim sdHEADER, nHEADER As Range
    Dim wsData, wsCoCd, wsBank, wsContact, wsBankHeader, wsCoCdHeader, wsContactHeader, wsDataHeader, wsn As Worksheet
    Dim wsBankn, wsCoCdn, wsContactn, wsDatan As Worksheet
    Dim wb1, wbBankn, wbCoCdn, wbContactn, wbDatan As Workbook
    Dim fdn As FileDialog
    Dim PickFolder, Bankn, CoCdn, Contactn, Datan, HEADER As String
    Dim LastCol1, LastRow1, LastRown, NrHeadBank, NrHeadCoCd, NrHeadContact, NrHeadData, i As Integer

'Choose initial folder for file picker
    PickFolder = "C:\"

'Set up a file dialog to pick the files containing the data
    Set fdn = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

'Activate file dialog and send to "CancelBox" if user presses cancel

   With fdn
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Please select the file containing the Bank data"
    .Filters.Clear
    .InitialFileName = PickFolder
    If .Show = True Then
    Bankn = fdn.SelectedItems(1)
    With fdn
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Please select the file containing the Company Code data"
        .Filters.Clear
        .InitialFileName = PickFolder
        If .Show = True Then
        CoCdn = fdn.SelectedItems(1)
        With fdn
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .Title = "Please select the file containing the Contact data"
            .Filters.Clear
            .InitialFileName = PickFolder
            If .Show = True Then
            Contactn = fdn.SelectedItems(1)
            With fdn
                .AllowMultiSelect = False
                .Title = "Please select the file containing the Report"
                .Filters.Clear
                .InitialFileName = PickFolder
                If .Show = True Then
                Datan = fdn.SelectedItems(1)
                Else: GoTo CancelBox
                End If
            End With
            Else: GoTo CancelBox
            End If
        End With
        Else: GoTo CancelBox
        End If
    End With
    Else: GoTo CancelBox
    End If
End With
'Increase Makro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Define worksheet(1) & worsheet(n)
    Set wsData = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("General Data")
    Set wsBank = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Bank Data")
    Set wsCoCd = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CoCd Data")
    Set wsContact = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Contact Person")

'Add Worksheets that contain the respective headers to the end of the workbook
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsBankHeader = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        wsBankHeader.name = "Bank Headers"
        Set wsCoCdHeader = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        wsCoCdHeader.name = "CoCd Headers"
        Set wsContactHeader = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        wsContactHeader.name = "Contact Headers"
        Set wsDataHeader = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        wsDataHeader.name = "Data Headers"
    End With

'Fill the added worksheets with the required headers
    With wsBankHeader
        .Range("A1") = "LIFNR"
        .Range("B1") = "KTOKK"
        .Range("C1") = "NAME1"
        .Range("D1") = "BANKS"
        .Range("E1") = "BANKL"
        .Range("F1") = "BANKN"
        .Range("G1") = "BVTYP"
        .Range("H1") = "IBAN"
    End With

    With wsCoCdHeader
        .Range("A1") = "LIFNR"
        .Range("B1") = "BUKRS"
        .Range("C1") = "KTOKK"
        .Range("D1") = "NAME1"
        .Range("E1") = "AKONT"
        .Range("F1") = "ZUAWA"
        .Range("G1") = "FDGRV"
        .Range("H1") = "FRGRP"
        .Range("I1") = "ZTERM"
        .Range("J1") = "REPRF"
        .Range("K1") = "ZWELS"
    End With

    With wsContactHeader
        .Range("A1") = "LIFNR"
        .Range("B1") = "KTOKK"
        .Range("C1") = "NAME1"
        .Range("D1") = "NAMEV"
        .Range("E1") = "NAME1_01"
        .Range("F1") = "SMTP_ADDR"
        .Range("G1") = "ABTNR"
        .Range("H1") = "TEL_COUNTRY"
        .Range("I1") = "TEL_NUMBER"
        .Range("J1") = "FAX_COUNTRY"
        .Range("K1") = "FAX_NUMBER"
    End With

   With wsDataHeader
        .Range("A1") = "LIFNR"
        .Range("B1") = "KTOKK"
        .Range("C1") = "NAME1"
        .Range("D1") = "NAME2"
        .Range("E1") = "NAME3"
        .Range("F1") = "SORTL"
        .Range("G1") = "STRAS"
        .Range("H1") = "PSTLZ"
        .Range("I1") = "LAND1"
        .Range("J1") = "SPRAS"
        .Range("K1") = "TELF1"
        .Range("L1") = "J_1KFTIND"
    End With



'Count number of columns in each Header sheet
    NrHeadBank = wsBankHeader.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Column

    NrHeadCoCd = wsCoCdHeader.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Column

    NrHeadContact = wsContactHeader.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Column
    NrHeadData = wsDataHeader.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Column



'Define sheets in picked workbooks
    Set wbBankn = Workbooks.Open(Bankn)
    Set wsBankn = wbBankn.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wbCoCdn = Workbooks.Open(CoCdn)
    Set wsCoCdn = wbCoCdn.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wbContactn = Workbooks.Open(Contactn)
    Set wsContactn = wbContactn.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wbDatan = Workbooks.Open(Datan)
    Set wsDatan = wbDatan.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Find last non empty column and row in sheets in wb1
    LastRow1 = wsData.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
    LastCol1 = wsData.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Column

    LastRow2 = wsContact.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
    LastCol2 = wsContact.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Column

    LastRow3 = wsBank.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
    LastCol3 = wsBank.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Column

    LastRow4 = wsCoCd.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
    LastCol4 = wsCoCd.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Column

'Fill sheet(General Data) with data from wbdata
    For i = 1 To NrHeadData
'Define what header to look for in every loop
    '"Cells" has no automatic allocation, so always define ws when working with multiple wb & ws!
        HEADER = wsDataHeader.Cells(1, i)
'get position of where HEADER is in sheet(n)
        wsDatan.Activate   'is required because of the way excel works
        Set nHEADER = wsDatan.Range("A1").EntireRow.Find(HEADER, LookAt:=xlWhole)
'Find lastrow in wsDatan
        LastRown = wsDatan.Cells(Rows.Count, nHEADER.Column).End(xlUp).Row
'get position of where HEADER is in
        wsData.Activate
        Set sdHEADER = wsData.Range(wsData.Cells(1, 1), wsData.Cells(LastRow1, LastCol1)).Find(HEADER, LookAt:=xlWhole)
'Fill wsData
        wsData.Range(wsData.Cells(LastRow1 + 1, sdHEADER.Column), wsData.Cells(LastRow1 + LastRown - 1, sdHEADER.Column)) = wsDatan.Range(wsDatan.Cells(2, nHEADER.Column), wsDatan.Cells(LastRown, nHEADER.Column)).Value
    Next i

 'Fill sheet(General Data) with data from wbcontact
    For i = 1 To NrHeadContact
        HEADER = wsContactHeader.Cells(1, i)
        wsContactn.Activate
        Set nHEADER = wsContactn.Range("A1").EntireRow.Find(HEADER, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        LastRown = wsContactn.Cells(Rows.Count, nHEADER.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        wsContact.Activate
        Set sdHEADER = wsContact.Range(wsContact.Cells(1, 1), wsContact.Cells(LastRow2, LastCol2)).Find(HEADER, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        wsContact.Range(wsContact.Cells(LastRow2 + 1, sdHEADER.Column), wsContact.Cells(LastRow2 + LastRown - 1, sdHEADER.Column)) = wsContactn.Range(wsContactn.Cells(2, nHEADER.Column), wsContactn.Cells(LastRown, nHEADER.Column)).Value
    Next i

'Fill sheet(Bank) with data from wbbank
    For i = 1 To NrHeadBank
        HEADER = wsBankHeader.Cells(1, i)
        wsBankn.Activate
        Set nHEADER = wsBankn.Range("A1").EntireRow.Find(HEADER, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        LastRown = wsBankn.Cells(Rows.Count, nHEADER.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        wsBank.Activate
        Set sdHEADER = wsBank.Range(wsBank.Cells(1, 1), wsBank.Cells(LastRow3, LastCol3)).Find(HEADER, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        wsBank.Range(wsBank.Cells(LastRow3 + 1, sdHEADER.Column), wsBank.Cells(LastRow3 + LastRown - 1, sdHEADER.Column)) = wsBankn.Range(wsBankn.Cells(2, nHEADER.Column), wsBankn.Cells(LastRown, nHEADER.Column)).Value
    Next i

'Fill sheet(CoCd) with data from wbCoCd
    For i = 1 To NrHeadCoCd
        HEADER = wsCoCdHeader.Cells(1, i)
        wsCoCdn.Activate
        Set nHEADER = wsCoCdn.Range("A1").EntireRow.Find(HEADER, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        LastRown = wsCoCdn.Cells(Rows.Count, nHEADER.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        wsCoCd.Activate
        Set sdHEADER = wsCoCd.Range(wsCoCd.Cells(1, 1), wsCoCd.Cells(LastRow4, LastCol4)).Find(HEADER, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        wsCoCd.Range(wsCoCd.Cells(LastRow4 + 1, sdHEADER.Column), wsCoCd.Cells(LastRow4 + LastRown - 1, sdHEADER.Column)) = wsBankn.Range(wsBankn.Cells(2, nHEADER.Column), wsBankn.Cells(LastRown, nHEADER.Column)).Value
    Next i

'Delete the Header Sheets that were added, close opened workbooks and reset sheet settings
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wsBankHeader.Delete
    wsCoCdHeader.Delete
    wsContactHeader.Delete
    wsDataHeader.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    wbBankn.Close
    wbCoCdn.Close
    wbContactn.Close
    wbDatan.Close
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

CancelBox:
    MsgBox "You didn't select all the files required for this makro. Please restart this makro and try again"

    End Sub
```